# Grails commands missing on netbeans?

Tags: grails, netbeans, command

I'm using Netbeans for my project with grails, but I'm having a problem with the grails commands, but I keep getting this message:

https://s12.postimg.org/713mrxofx/Sem_t_tulo.png

Does anyone know how to fix it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IMO, Netbeans is only good for Java. Grails support in Netbeans is buggy, immature, and painful. I tried it few months back, then gave up, and ended up setting Grails in my Emacs -- I don't like Eclipse. So, I would suggest you do the same; switch to some other IDE for Grails, at least.

IntelliJ has a good support, but community version doesn't have it; few are using that, nonetheless.

Try Eclipse, it has better Grails support than Netbeans.